# List share between two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, locks

I would like in c++ to share a list between two threads. I would like very simple not by taking FIFO or Shared memory so i just use mutex and locks.

I tried this way and its working :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <mutex> 
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <list>

std::list<int> myList;
std::mutex list_mutex; 

    void client(){
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(list_mutex);

        myList.push_back(4);

    };
    
 

    void server(){

      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(list_mutex);

      myList.push_back(2);

    };

    void print(std::list<int> const &list)
    {
    for (auto const& i: list) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
    };

    int main(int ac, char** av)
    {
      
      std::mutex list_mutex; 

      std::thread t1(client);
      std::thread t2(server);


      t1.join();
      t2.join();

      print(myList);
      std::cout<<"test";

      return 0;
    }
```

And it print me this

```
24test
```

**This is fine it work HOWEVER i'm not sure i'm using the same lock ? My supervisor wants me to have explicit Lock/Unlock in the code. At least if i can use the same mutex?**

Thank you very much to help me

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know now what to do , I know also i dont have to send a thank you message , but really nice from you , not so usual to have nice and polite people with noobs like me.

Comment: Thanks! You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ted's comment is important, what you are working with are threads, not processes. Processes don't share memory (besides using Shared Memory, but you wanted to avoid that). Threads share their entire memory space with each other.

You also mentioned that your supervisor wants you to use unlock/lock sections. You could do this by calling:

```
list_mutex.lock()
... critical section ...
list_mutx.unlock()
```

But you already do this implicitly by constructing a `lock_guard`. The `lock_guard` locks when you create it and unlocks at the end of the current scope.

As noted by Ted, you need to remove the second declaration of list_mutex (inside main).

Comment: You got my vote, but you could add a note about the `std::mutex list_mutex;` that is declared in `main`. Snce it's unused, it can be removed.

Comment: Thank you Jack ,  but do std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(list_mutex); is usefull in BOTH threads client&&Serveur?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think he can actually remove the std::mutex because that is used by the `lock_guard`'s. They are using it like you would in `list_mutex.lock()` but doing it inside their constructor and deconstructor (`list_mutex.unlock()`).

Comment: @Jack The mutex declared in `main` isn't used anywhere. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bda48TYvP)

Comment: @et11enne Yes the lock is needed in both server and client, this is because you are modifying the shared variable in each. So those operations need to be serial (only one person doing it at once) so that there is consistent state after each.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah I see what you mean, yes et11enne, you need to remove the double declaration of list_mutex (the second time is in main), I will modify the answer.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for your support so i removed the lock_guard and replaced it with lock and unlock... I preffered lock_guards it seems to be way more easy to use

Comment: @et11enne Yes and the `lock_guard`s are also safer since they will unlock even if an exception is thrown while the lock is held. Manual locking/unlocking should very rarely be done, if ever.